# CSS _ HTML: my DIVs overlap despite I have set a relevant height and HTML element div are blocks by default

Tags: html, css

Here my sandbox: https://codepen.io/joondoe/pen/VJyxqN

here an image of the situation: [image]

**I m wondering why the first "awesome content" fails to get 300vh, and the following text seems to overlap on the first?**

I would the two div to succeed one after another, instead, they purely overlap, how it is possible?

It seems to me I have set a relevant height and width, the div are basically [block element by default](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp),

here my snippet:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>seamless_background_test</title>
     <style>
      html,body{
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
      }
      .seamless_background{
       min-height: auto;
       width: 100%;
       /*bg-color bg-image position/bg-size bg-repeat bg-origin bg-clip bg-attachment initial|inherit*/
       background: url(./seamless_background_test2a.jpg) center repeat ;
    
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
      }
    
      .content_container{
       min-height: 300vh;
       background: orange;
       width: 75%;
       margin:auto;  
      }
    
      .content h1{   
       padding:15px;
       color:rgb(140, 49, 0);
    
       display:flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
      }
    
      #wind_content{ 
       position:relative;  
       
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
    
       margin:auto;
       top: 15vh;
    
       background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    
       font-style:Arial;
       font-size: 1.5em; 
    
       display:flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
      }
    
      
    
      #grass_content{ 
       position:relative;  
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
    
       margin:auto;
       top: 15vh;
    
       background:rgb(197, 245, 66);
    
       font-style:Arial;
       font-size: 1.5em; 
    
       display:flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
      }
    
    
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="seamless_background" >
      <div id="wind_content" >
       <div class="content_container">
        <h1>I am an awesome content :)!<h2>
       <div>
      </div>
    
      <div id="grass_content" >
       <div class="content_container">
        <h1>I am an awesome content :)!<h2>
       <div>
      </div>
     <div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's overlapping? Maybe a screenshot? Both the Codepen and the SO example look stacked to me... Latest Chrome, Mac

Comment: that said I'd remove most of your heights and let the content naturally push down the page using margin/padding.

Comment: @BryceHowitson thanks for your answer Bryce, image added.

Comment: you are closing a div using `<div>` and not `</div>` (voting to close a typo issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a lot of opening tags you haven't close.

I didn't really understand about the word "overlapping".

But I've closed all opened tags and i think that is what you're looking for

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>seamless_background_test</title>
     <style>
      html,body{
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
      }
      .seamless_background{
       min-height: auto;
       width: 100%;
       /*bg-color bg-image position/bg-size bg-repeat bg-origin bg-clip bg-attachment initial|inherit*/
       background: url(./seamless_background_test2a.jpg) center repeat ;
    
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: column;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
      }
    
      .content_container{
       min-height: 300vh;
       background: orange;
       width: 75%;
       margin:auto;  
      }
    
      .content h1{   
       padding:15px;
       color:rgb(140, 49, 0);
    
       display:flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
      }
    
      #wind_content{ 
       position:relative;  
       
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
    
       margin:auto;
       top: 15vh;
    
       background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    
       font-style:Arial;
       font-size: 1.5em; 
    
       display:flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
      }
    
      
    
      #grass_content{ 
       position:relative;  
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
    
       margin:auto;
       top: 15vh;
    
       background:rgb(197, 245, 66);
    
       font-style:Arial;
       font-size: 1.5em; 
    
       display:flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
      }
    
    
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="seamless_background" >
      <div id="wind_content" >
       <div class="content_container">
        <h1>I am an awesome content :)!</h1>
       </div>
      </div>
    
      <div id="grass_content" >
       <div class="content_container">
        <h1>I am an awesome content :)!</h1>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```